# Making ESS recognize #'

Tags: ess

I just upgraded to modified Emacs

http://vgoulet.act.ulaval.ca/en/emacs/mac/

When I used to work in R files, `#'` was recognized by `ess-mode` such that hitting `[Enter]` at the end of a line that began with `#'` would start the next line with `#'`. After the upgrade, it does not seem to recognize `#'` as a special form.

Any ideas what variable I need to set?

Comment: This should work out of the box, and it does for me with the same versions of Emacs and ESS as are in the distribution you use. Perhaps file a bug with the folks that maintain the package you've used? The best help for debugging these custom distributions is the distributor - I can't reproduce your problem with standard Emacs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I commented out `(require 'ess-site)` in `/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/Resources/site-lisp/site-start.el`
2. Installed the package from ELPA.
3. In my `.emacs`, I included the statements:

   ```
   (require 'package)
   (require 'ess-site)
   ```